# Перестали рассылаются пуши через ApnsPHP, кодировка

Tags: php, ios, utf-8

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой при отправке пушей средствами ApnsPHP.

после перевода сайта в кодировку utf-8 пуши перестали доходить. Полез разбираться, выяснилось, что при попытке послать латиницей, например **test** - уведомление доходит аж 3 раза , но при этом ответ *"Writes: Internal error (127 by written in instead of 105 bytes)"*

т.е. пишет ошибку, но отправляет 3 раза.

при попытке отправить русскими **тест**, пишет туже ошибку, но не доходят

поискал в инете, что пишут по этому поводу - что проблема в

> $nLen = strlen ($aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION']);

в файле Push.php

заменил на

> $nLen = mb_strlen($aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION'], 'latin1');

латиница теперь рассылается без ошибок и доходит один раз. русский не доходит.

ставлю:

> $nLen = mb_strlen($aMessage ['BINARY_NOTIFICATION'],'utf-8');

не помогает, не доходят. что делать?